# How can I add a "selected" style to a siFR a:link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sifr

I got a menu powered by [SIFR](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/What+is+sIFR) like this:

```
<h2><a href="images/logo.jpg">IDENTIIES</a></h2><br>
```

I've setup the different states of the a:link style and I'd like this link to stay in another color when it has been clicked on (until another link is clicked on).

I think this has something to do with javascript, but I can't make this work.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Flash does not support this. JavaScript workarounds might be possible, but are workarounds at best. I advise you do not use sIFR for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a selected class to the link that has been selected you should have to different selectors. One for not selected and one for selected.

```
<h2 class="selected"><a href="images/logo.jpg">IDENTIIES</a></h2>
<h2><a href="images/logo.jpg">NOT SELECTED</a></h2>
```

Then use these selectors for sIFR replacements with a different style. Could be something like this:

```
sIFR.replace(YourFont, { 
  selector: 'h2 a',
  css: [ '.sIFR-root {color: #FF0000;}' ]
});

sIFR.replace(YourFont, { 
  selector: 'h2 a.selected',
  css: [ '.sIFR-root {color: #FFFF00;}' ]
});
```

Comment: (That wouldn't work because sIFR can't replace `<a>` elements directly. You should replace the `<h2>` and put the class on the `<h2>` as well.)